# Регулярное выражение только 0-1 раз в строке

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Строка из 1-10 символов, в строке может быть точка (0 или 1 раз), но точка не должна быть первой или последней в строке (строка с точкой в нутри или без точки должна быть 1-10 символов).
Можно ли 1-ой строкой регулярного выражения проверить такое условие?

Например:

```
. //НЕправильно
.aa //НЕправильно
aa22. //НЕправильно
a.a2.2 //НЕправильно

a // правильно
aa2.2 // правильно
aa.22 // правильно
```

Что-то вроде такого на регулярном можно?

```
^(([^.]+\.?[^.]+)|([^.]+)){1,10}$ // в этом примере можно записывать более 10 символов
```

Или длину нужно отдельно проверять или все же можно написать все 1 строкой? Хочу для себя понять возможно ли, если да то как?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57822/discussion-on-question-by-bsbak----0-1---).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Строка из 1-10 символов

```
^.{1,10}$
```

> в строке может быть точка (0 или 1 раз)

```
^[^.]*\.?[^.]*$
```

> но точка не должна быть первой или последней в строке

```
^(?!\.|.*\.$)
```

> Можно ли 1-ой строкой регулярного выражения проверить такое условие?

```
^(?!\.|.*\.$)(?=[^.]*\.?[^.]*$).{1,10}$
```

Вот пример. На пустое поле внимание обращать не стоит - это особая обработка браузером. Пустая строка под регулярку не подходит, но если браузеру не сказать, что поле обязательно, то он это даже не проверяет.

```css
span { display: none; }
input:valid ~ .valid { display: inline; color: green; }
input:invalid ~ .invalid { display: inline; color: red; }
```

```html
<input type="text" pattern="^(?!\.|.*\.$)(?=[^.]*\.?[^.]*$).{1,10}$" autofocus>
<span class="valid">Всё шикарно</span>
<span class="invalid">Нет, так нельзя...</span>
```

Comment: мне просто любопытно, как так получилось что спустя несколько лет вы каким то образом заметили "недосказанность"?:D

Comment: @skingreek, вот так: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9530/178988